# What does .end(data) of a variable mean in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I sow [in this link](http://book.mixu.net/node/ch3.html#3-4-implementing-message-receiving-and-broadcasting-on-the-server-side) a code containing the following :

```
var client = clients.pop();
    client.end(//some data here));
```

where Clients is an array with some objects.

what is the functionality of .end(..) of a variable?

Thank you!

Comment: See https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_end_data_encoding_callback

Comment: @DMan hello,the link you added is for request not for a variable

Comment: `clients` is a list of requests, so when you pop one off and store it into the variable `client`, `client` _is_ a request, and so you can call `.end()` on it. Does that make sense?

Comment: @DMan yes ,thank you very much sir

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth dissecting things for the sake of clarity.

```
// myObject, like client, is an object
var myObject = { data: 123 };

// object slots are referenced by objectName.slotName
// a new slot can be defined "on the fly" using this notation
myObject.flurpies = function () { return 234; };

// myObject.flurpies, like client.end, points to a function

// a function can be called by adding () following the function

// this function call should return 234
myObject.flurpies()
```

Hope that helps...